# how to write select query in PostgreSQL to iterate over an array which is returned by a select query

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, foreach, subquery

```
SELECT b_items_p_id FROM  public.box WHERE b_id =1
```

[and this is what it returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mueQw.png):

```
{1,3,5}
```

Now on each of these value, i.e., 1, 3 and 5 I want to run another select query:

```
select p_desc from public.products where p_id = 1
```

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. PS Time to follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join `box` and `products` using the `any()` operator, like so:

```
select p_desc 
from public.box b 
inner join public.products p on p.p_id = any(b.b_items_p_id)
where b.b_id =1
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot GMB. It worked.

But is there any way of doing it using for loop or foreach ?

Comment: @octogenex: why would you want to use a loop, when you can do this with a straight query? Loops are painfully slow in SQL. Use the query instead.